# When I compile .c file it always creates .exe file with name 'a'

Tags: c, gcc

I use GCC compiler to compile and run C program on CMD.
When I compile C program using command `gcc hello.c` it creates an executable file file with name `a.exe` but when I use IDE it uses the name same as .c file as `hello.exe`.
Is it possible to create .exe file name same as .c file on CMD?

Answer (score 7):

Just tell GCC the output name you want.

```
gcc hello.c -o hello
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify the name of the executable

```
gcc -c hello.c // compiling

gcc -o hello hello.o // linking
         ^------------------------- name of the executable
```

you can do the compiling and the linking in one command

```
gcc -o hello hello.c
         ^------------------------- name of the executable
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the syntax of output. Following is the description of the command:

```
$ gcc [options] [source files] [object files] -o output file
```

In your case you should execute the commands as following:

```
$ gcc myfile.c -o myfile
$ ./myfile
```

For more descriptions and more optimized ways refer to the following url:
http://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-o.htm